# how to create a Floating popup video player in android?

Tags: android

**how to create a Floating popup video player in android?**

In my app i want floating popup window .i don't know the concept help?

like Floating YouTube Popup Player

please

Comment: Floating YouTube Popup Player

Comment: Do you mean that user should be able to drag it over the screen?

Answer (score 7):

There is open source, they did all you want. Link as below:

http://flavienlaurent.com/blog/2013/08/28/each-navigation-drawer-hides-a-viewdraghelper/

https://github.com/pedrovgs/DraggablePanel

Comment: Awesome links. I was familiar with the second but the first is new and a must read!

Answer (score 1):

Create a [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) which contains a [VideoView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html)

Comment: I don't know how Floating YouTube Popup Player is, but you can drag a popupWindow on the screen. And I'm assuming that UI design is not a problem for you

Comment: no friend its problem to me.i want play video on any activity but popup window its show on current activity only

Answer (score 1):

1. Make AbsoluteLayout with fill_parent for width and height and add VideoView on this. Also, you can implement Frame/Linear layour with padding and background as frame for your VideoView
2. Add onTouchListener for VideoView and implement standart drag behavior in this listener by updating coordinates of VideoView
3. Add this AbsoluteLayout on your activity layout.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a second activity in your Manifest.xml and call it something like MainActivity2,

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity2" android:exported="true" android:label="@string/app_name">
```

update the manifest of your Android App and and add an intent on a button inside the activity you are calling from, this way when you click on the button the window will ‘pop out’

```
val context = LocalContext.current
                    val i = (Intent(context, MainActivity2::class.java))

                    context.startActivity(i)}
```