# floating video player (like youtube player ) in android

Tags: android, video, android-mediaplayer, popupwindow, android-video-player

In my app i need to implement  floating video player ( like youtube player). i gone through the below urls but not able to solve my issue. I don't know where to start and what to use .
Please someone help me

[how to create a Floating popup video player in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17190042/how-to-create-a-floating-popup-video-player-in-android)

[how to create a Floating popup video player in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17190042/how-to-create-a-floating-popup-video-player-in-android)

[What APIs in Android is Facebook using to create Chat Heads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975988/what-apis-in-android-is-facebook-using-to-create-chat-heads)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can achieve this by using service with Window manager, there is an excellent sample application available on github
https://github.com/marshallino16/FloatingView, this will guide you to achieve your requirements which are listed above

Answer (score 1):

To make floating player you need to work on widgets. it is known as picture in picture mode. step is as below

1) add dependency for support media

2) create player layout

3) add player click event (touch & onclick listener)

4) add broadcast receiver to detect event on player view.

5) Start player from activity.

You can find link on github for picture in picture mode android example OR you can [get reference here](https://www.blueappsoftware.com/floating-video-player-like-youtube-player/)